# Airflow: Use LivyBatchOperator for submitting pyspark applications in yarn

Tags: hadoop-yarn, livy, airflow, apache-spark-2.3

I have encountered something called **LivyBatchOperator** but unable to find a very good example for it to submit pyspark applications in airflow. Any info on this would really be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I come across this [blog post](https://www.shortn0tes.com/2020/03/airflow-livy-spark.html) which can help you to walk through available options on Airflow + Spark.

[Here](https://github.com/panovvv/airflow-livy-operators/tree/master/airflow_home/dags) is an example of LivyBatchOperator and [here](https://pypi.org/project/airflow-livy-operators/) is on how to install airflow-livy-operators.

I would recommend below options :

1. ****AWS EMR** :** Use **EmrAddStepsOperator**
2. **Regular Spark Cluster :** Use above mechanism to set up Livy operators in airflow. This will give you a slick configuration from the airflow servers perspective as well as using Livy in front of spark cluster.

Let me know your response !

Comment: Thanks, the respective blogs helped me to start with. Can we pass a zip file in **file** parameter and a **class_name** in submitting pyspark  applications through livy?

Comment: Yes there is an option to pass ZIP files using files argument not using file.
files - Used to send list of ZIP files
file - In case of python , use this as entry point to run the spark driver
class_name - This will be class name for Java/Spark main class.

Refer here for Livy API documentations which is a back bone of this LivyBatchOperator. https://livy.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/rest-api.html

Comment: I am getting issues when I tried this

`LivyBatchOperator( task_id = 'spark_job',  file = '/abc/xyz.zip', 
  class_name = 'src.foo.py', py-files), "spark.submit.pyFiles":'/abc/lmn.zip' 
where src.foo.py is a file in xyz.zip`

`Error: --py-files given but primary resource is not a Python script`. @Abdul